# GStreamer: Output speeds up and slows down during play back when transcoding between MJPEG and H264

Tags: video, gstreamer, video-encoding

I am trying to convert video from a cheap USB HDMI Capture card into something more usable.

The device outputs a 1080p 30fps stream of MJPEG, and I'd like to transcode into H264 in a mkv container. I am using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Buster, so Hardware Transcoding is necessary.

`gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! jpegparse ! v4l2jpegdec ! queue ! videoconvert ! v4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=out.mkv`

With the above command I get reasonable quality without maxing out the CPU, but the playback speed of the output file speeds up and slows down.

Am I missing something? Any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using hardware `omxmjpegdec` for hardware decoding of mjpeg stream from your `v4l2src` stream. much of CPU is used up in `MJPEG` decoding from your UVC card (USB HDMI capture). But `omxmjpegdec` doesnt work mostly for seemingly no reason at all

more importantly pi can do hardware h264 encoding  use `omxh264enc` instead of `v4l2h264enc`

```
gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! jpegparse ! v4l2jpegdec ! queue ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=out.mkv
```